# Is it possible to do "in memory" hosting with ASP.NET MVC applications, similar to Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am writing an ASP.net MVC 4 application, and I am thinking about using "in memory" hosting to write integration tests for my custom action filters.

There are a few examples on the web on how to do this with Web API (eg http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/asp-net-web-api-integration-testing-with-in-memory-hosting/) but I haven't seen any example with MVC.

Is it possible to do "in memory" hosting with MVC applications?
If so does anyone have any examples or could they point me to any articles that do this?

Answer (score 5):

You might be interested in [MvcIntegrationTestFramework](https://github.com/gregoryjscott/MvcIntegrationTestFramework). It is not the freshest one but I works. Here is self-explaining example from their page:

```
AppHost.Simulate("MyMvcApp").Start(browsingSession =>
{
    var loginResult = browsingSession.Post("Users/Login/", 
                                           new { UserName = "aaa", Password = "bbb" });
    Assert.That(loginResult.Response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(200));

    var result = browsingSession.Post("Money/Create/", 
                                      new { Amount = "1,000,000" });
    Assert.That(result.Response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(200));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Looks along the track that I am looking for but I'd be hesitant to use such an old and unsupported framework. Are there any other simmilar frameworks?

Comment: @user1838438 unfortunately I'm not aware of any, but I know people are using this one, [here is an example](http://blog.bakermatt.com/2013/03/10/using-mvcintegrationtestframework-for-asp-net-mvc-functional-testing/)